# Can humidity changes induce stacking-sequence changes?

Tags: geochemistry, mineralogy, humidity, crystallography

My understanding is that some minerals with layered crystal structures will reversibly absorb water with changes in humidity. Are there any minerals where this reversible absorption leads to a stacking-sequence change in the crystal structure?

By stacking-sequence change, I mean that the relative alignment of atomic layers shifts, such as in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but most of these are not considered reversible without heating. I'll let someone who knows more answer.